# write zip array vertical in csv

Tags: python, csv

is there ways to display zipped text vertically in csv ?? I tried many difference type of \n ',' but still can't get the array to be vertical

[image: Excel csv]

```
if __name__ == '__main__': #start of program
master = Tk()
newDirRH = "C:/VSMPlots"
FileName = "J123"
TypeName = "1234"
Field = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Court = [5,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3]

for field, court in zip(Field, Court):
   stringText = ','.join((str(FileName), str(TypeName), str(Field), str(Court)))

newfile = newDirRH + "/Try1.csv"
text_file = open(newfile, "w")
x = stringText
text_file.write(x)
text_file.close()
print "Done"
```

This is the method i am looking for for your Code i can't seem to add new columns as all the column will repeat 10x

[image]

Comment: You are not writing CSV data. You are writing Python string representations of lists.

Comment: i not very sure, but the output is a excel.csv format thats why i thought it would be in csv data

Comment: Python lists have commas, so Excel will split on those, but note the `[` and `]` in the cells as well..

Comment: You were writing the *whole* `Field` and `Court` lists to the file. Each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not writing CSV data. You are writing Python string representations of lists. You are writing the whole `Field` and `Court` lists each iteration of your loop, instead of writing `field` and `court`, and Excel sees the comma in the Python string representation:

```
J123,1234,[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],[5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
J123,1234,[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],[5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
etc.
```

while you wanted to write:

```
J123,1234,1,5
J123,1234,2,4
etc.
```

Use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to produce CSV files:

```
import csv

with open(newfile, "wb") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for field, court in zip(Field, Court):
        writer.writerow([FileName, TypeName, field, court])
```

Note the `with` statement; it takes care of closing the open file object for you. The `csv` module also makes sure everything is converted to strings.

If you want to write something only on the first row, keep a counter with your items; `enumerate()` makes that easy:

```
with open(newfile, "wb") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    # row of headers
    writer.writerow(['FileName', 'TypeName', 'field', 'court'])

    for i, (field, court) in enumerate(zip(Field, Court)):
        row = [[FileName, TypeName] if i == 0 else ['', '']
        writer.writerow(row + [field, court])
```

Comment: i would prefer to stick to my current way thanks! I just need to fix this vertical problem and i am done >.<

Comment: @EdgeYewe: Why have a dog and bark yourself? In any case, write `str(field)` not `str(Field)` to the file.

Comment: And don't use capitalized names for normal variables. There is a string (!) convention to use those for class names only.

Comment: 'string convention'? You mean there is a Python style guide that tells us this. :-) I try to focus on the OP code problems more than style issues; communication is easier that way.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is there any way for me to select which Column i want it to be written at ?

Comment: @EdgeYewe: Why don't you add *expected* output to your question? `csv.writerow()` takes a list; each entry in the list is a column. If you want to alter the order of those columns, alter the list positions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yup writer.writerow([FileName, TypeName, field, court]) But the filename and typename also repeat 10 times

Comment: @EdgeYewe: That's because your original code did the same; did you want to write those to a separate row? Then do so! `writer.writerow([Filename, TypeName])` first, then the rest is just `writer.writerow([field, court])`. That's why I am asking for an output example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried writing that but it still can't work. i will post the example below.. thank you.

Comment: @EdgeYewe: Updated; thanks for the example, a picture speaks a thousand words.